# When extracting specific bits from a register does the extracted value have to have the same size as the register?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I am currently extracting 9 bits (the last 9) from a 16 bit register. I don't have a problem with extracting the bits, however when I extract the bits is my extracted value going to have 7 '0's at the end? A representation:

Register:              1100101011110011

Bit mask:              1111111110000000

Is my extracted value: 110010101 (405)

or is it:              1100101010000000 (51840)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `1100101010000000`  if you are using `and (&)` for extraction

Comment: The second, but you can easily print result of `Register & mask`.....

Comment: Show your code. If you are asking this question, then you _do have_  a problem extracting the bits.

Comment: You want to read how the bit-operators work. That has nothing to do with a register, MCU, etc. It is not even C-specific, but programming basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are easily achieved.

```
(unsigned short)reg >> (16-9) == 405, // where as
reg & bitmask == 51840
```

Some "controllers", such as x86 with BMI2 extension support however bit extraction with the bitmask `PEXT reg, bitmask` would give 405.

The specific answer the question in the title is no; the output variable has to contain just enough bits.

```
unsigned char eight_bits = reg >> 8;  // get's top 8 bits
```

Comment: The cast to `unsigned short` is irrelevant and missleading. If anything, you should cast to `unsigned int` to avoid implemention defined shifting of the sign-bit.

Comment: @Olaf: that's not correct. Casting to unsigned int will copy the sign bit, producing 1111111110010101 (if the register is defined `short`)

Comment: An `unsigned int` has not sign bit! Which type has your `reg`? Hardware peripheral register should always be unsigned integers, so the cast will not produce any eiher. Let apart the conversion from signed to unsigned `int` is well defined.

Comment: Yes, conversion from signed short to unsigned int is well defined (going from short -> int -> unsigned int) and it replicates the 15th bit to bit positions 16..31.

Comment: Read my comment carefully **again**. And why do you assume `unsigned int` has 32 bits?

Comment: Casting a signed short to unsigned int would copy the sign bit all over the top bits of the destination variable. It would be possible to pre-mask (reg & 0xffff) >> 7, or post-mask (reg >> 7) & 0x1ff. Casting `short` to `unsigned short` effectively implements this pre-masking. And yes, I'm assuming that int _can_ be wider than short. There are plenty of unknowns in the question and I'm trying to assume the worst.

Comment: @chux if `short` is 16-bit and `int` 32-bit, and `reg` signed 16-bit, then those two casts are very different (and the `unsigned short` cast probably gives the desired behaviour of right-shifting with zero-fill)

Comment: @M.M  Agreed.  Of course that is correct.  Comment removed.